# Android Clock which runs when device off

Tags: android, clock

I am creating an application, which will save the current time (with some delay eg. 2 hours) in file, when the user presses a button. Later on, the application will check if the time has passed and do some stuff...

So... I click button in application (time gets saved in file)... I quit application... shut-down phone... I turn it on after 1 hour, get back to application... and I will still have to  wait 1 hour until the application will let me do "something"...

**QUESTION:**

Is there a clock that cannot be changed by the user and keeps running when the device is turned off? I'm currently using `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`, which works fine, because even if users change the time in settings, `elapsedRealtime` stays the same. The problem is if the device gets turned off, because at every boot `elapsedRealtime` starts with 0.

I cannot use server time because application will not be connected to Internet.

If there is no such clock, please suggest me another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actualy, you have no chance to get "off" hardware clock data. hardware clocks was just on older phones in the new phones i think nobody need it so they dont build it in hardware. In the old phones there was "hardware" clock but in the new device is nothing like that i think. I did read something about that google want to make some framework or what to implement it. But there is no alarms what are able to start in off mode.

So i am sorry, but i think it is not possible right now..

Answer (score 0):

You could store your time in a database as a DateTime value, indicating Year Day Month Hour Second Millisecond, then you could request for a service to start on boot and read that data creating an alarm that triggers in the remaining time. I would give you a code example, but i'm not really good at java programming so it may be useless, anyway goodluck and try to implement this.

Answer (score -1):

You obviously need to save your data to non-volatile storage. When your app is paused/destroyed by the Android, you should take it as a threat and save your time values to the disks, and then when your app has started again your app should read the data you have written before and keep on running as it would normally.

Well when it comes to question how:

the simplest solution is to use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html),

the more complicated and the more flexible one is SQLite Database,

for more data on Android storage I will suggest: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: You didn't get my question. I already took care of storing data(i'm using internal storage in file). My question was about system clock that doesn't stop when device is off.